# Powershell - Execute function and then export to CSV

Tags: powershell, csv

What is the best way of executing a function and exporting the results to csv (file needs to be timestamped)?

I am currently producing a CSV which does not contain the correct details in the correct format.

```
function Print-Output() {
    $outputString = "hostname,os,lob"

    $Applications.Keys | ForEach-Object {
        $outputString+=",$_"
    }

    $outputString

    $ComputerObjects | ForEach-Object {
        $outputString="$($_.hostname),$($_.os),$($_.lob)"
        $currComputerObject = $_

        $currComputerObject.apps.Keys | ForEach-Object {
            $outputString+=",$($currComputerObject.apps[$_])".ToLower()
        }
        $outputString
    }

    $outputString
}

Print-Output | export-csv "results.csv"
```

Comment: Is the problem that you don't have the right data, or you don't have the right format? IOW, you've only shown "this is what I do" - not "this is what I get, but this other example is what I expect." At first blush, it looks like you're building CSV strings, then calling `Export-CSV` which will basically double-CSV your data. Export-CSV takes a collection of collections and outputs that to a CSV format - your data *shouldn't* be in a CSV format before calling the cmdlet.

Comment: you should pipe objects to export-csv, not comma separated strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$ComputerObjects | Export-csv "results.csv"
```

If you want to take a quick peek at the results,  you can try

```
Start results.csv
```

In my environment, this starts up Excel, and tells it to load the contents of the CSV file into a worksheet.  YMMV.